How do I find correlation between variables in a time series across multiple days?
I have data for each day, with a date/time, event, and when a secondary event gets triggered.
Date               | Time    | Event | Secondary Event Is Triggered
September 9, 2019  |12:00 AM | A     | No
September 9, 2019  |12:30 AM | A     | No
September 9, 2019  |01:00 AM |       | No
September 9, 2019  |01:30 AM | B     | No
...
September 9, 2019  |03:00 PM | E     | No
September 9, 2019  |03:30 PM |       | No
September 9, 2019  |04:00 PM |       | Yes
September 9, 2019  |11:30 PM | C     | Yes
September 10, 2019 |12:00 AM | D     | No
September 10, 2019 |12:30 AM | D     | No
...

Each day is completely isolated from each other, I know for sure nothing in one day causes the secondary event to trigger on another day - so we can assume whatever correlation exists is isolated within one day.
Given that there are multiple 'blocks' of this data one for each day of the month, for many months - What kind of analysis can be performed to get a better idea which event(s) are more probably associated with triggering the secondary event?
I was first looking at cross correlation for time series, using normal correlation but shifting the data in the last column by X amount of time to see which time lag amount could get the best correlation.
But what stumped me and why I posted this is because the time series I have isn't exactly continuous.  They are discrete blocks of time series data. So I wasn't sure how to proceed in that case.
EDIT: I need to add that the secondary event is triggered once and it persists throughout the remainder of the day.  So for the last column with 'yes' or 'no' if there is a continuous sequence of 'yes' then it just means that it is triggered at time t but persists through time t+1, t+2, t+3, etc.
So just to clarify further, it does not mean that Event A triggers one secondary event at time t, then Event B triggers secondary event at time t+1. I hope that makes sense.

Could you elaborate on what these events are? Some context would help.
